Checking if integers in list are consecutive - including cyclic iteration
I have a list of integers from 1 to n.
How can check if a subset of this list contains only consecutive numbers, accounting for a cyclic iteration (i.e. after n the iteration continues with 1)
Assuming my function is called foo and n=36, this is what I need:
# subsets could be bigger, using 3 elements as example

foo([1, 2, 3]) # True
foo([8, 9, 10]) # True
foo([35, 36, 1]) # True
foo([36, 1, 2]) # True

foo([1, 3, 4]) # False
foo([15, 17, 20]) # False
foo([3, 2, 1]) # False

My current approach is to create a string template with two cycles, and then compare if the string representation of the subset is contained in the template.
I'm sure there's a better way.
Edit:
I'm looking to check for unique, all consecutive subsets.
[1,2,3,1,2,3] should also be False (since after 3 I'd expect 4).
[1,3,4] should be False since after 1 I'd expect 2.
Edit 2:
the integers of the list 1-n are sequential.

No, sorry if not clear. The subset needs to have unique numbers. Your example should also return False

foo([1, 3, 4]) # False Why is this false?  3,4 certainly is a subset with consecutive numbers.

Hint: What is 37 % 36 in Python?

At the very least, you are going to have to pass n as an argument to foo, so that it knows whether or not 1 is the next value after 36. (Cyclic values are usually predicted on the modulo operator, so I already see a problem with assuming that 1, not 0, is the first element the implied set.)

@Ohm'sLawman look out 36%36 = 0 isn't (x%36) +1 better?

no issues with additional arguments. The full list itself is known beforehand, too.

"I have a list of integers from 1 to n." are we guaranteed they are consecutive integers? If so please add the word that in bold into the sentence.

@Elerium115 min elements is 2.

@Vorac yes, sorry if that wasn't clear.

@KenzoStaelens, I only wanted to raise the OP's awareness of the remainder operator. I didn't want to give the whole thing away. You are right though, there is a one unit offset between the "remainder space" and the "problem-as-stated space."

@Ohm'sLawman surely aware of % and figured it might be part of the solution. However, I haven't been able to wrap my head just around a solution, hence my question. Thanks for your hint, but I normally prefer more constructive comments

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __call__(self, l):
        prev = l[0]
        for el in l[1:]:
            if el == prev + 1 or (prev == self.n and el == 1):
                prev = el
            else:
                return False
        return True

foo = Foo(36)

print(foo([1, 2, 3])) # True
print(foo([8, 9, 10])) # True
print(foo([35, 36, 1])) # True
print(foo([36, 1, 2])) # True

print(foo([1, 3, 4])) # False
print(foo([15, 17, 20])) # False
print(foo([3, 2, 1])) # False


Thanks! But Foo(36)([1,2,1]) returns True which it should not

@Val got the condition wrong, fixed now.

Here is a short approach, keeping in mind, that you want to check the full list for consecutive numbers including "round-over":
def foo(lst, n=36):
 l=[]
 for i in range(len(lst)-1):
  l.append(lst[i+1]-lst[i]) #calculate differences
 print("input: ",lst)
 print("diff: ",l)
 for i in l:
  if not((i==1) or (i==-(n-1))):
   return False
 return True  

for j in [[1, 2, 3],[8, 9, 10],[35, 36, 1],[36, 1, 2],[1, 3, 4],[15, 17, 20],[3, 2, 1],[1,2,3,1,2,3]]:
 print(foo(j))
 print() 

It calculates the differences between neighbouring numbers in the list. If these are 1 they are consecutive. If the difference is -(n-1)=-35 both numbers are consecutive with "round-over". Otherwise the  difference shows the numbers are not consecutive by your definition, so the final result is False.
Result:
input:  [1, 2, 3]
diff:  [1, 1]
True

input:  [8, 9, 10]
diff:  [1, 1]
True

input:  [35, 36, 1]
diff:  [1, -35]
True

input:  [36, 1, 2]
diff:  [-35, 1]
True

input:  [1, 3, 4]
diff:  [2, 1]
False

input:  [15, 17, 20]
diff:  [2, 3]
False

input:  [3, 2, 1]
diff:  [-1, -1]
False

input:  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
diff:  [1, 1, -2, 1, 1]
False

